# What method in the Express.js library is used to close the server?

Tags: express

I've seen people try .close() but close doesn't seem to be a method in the Express library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express' `.listen()` method return an [`http.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpserver) instance that can be closed:

```
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();
const server  = app.listen(…);

…

server.close();
```